# Como traducir los componentes de un Form que hereda un MenuStrip en C#?

Tags: c#

En un proyecto en el que se inicia con un Form (hijo), de otro formulario (Padre) en donde se encuentra un menu strip, que posee una opcion para cambiar el idioma de todo el proyecto, como logro que al hacer click en ese cambio de idioma, ese formulario inicial se logre actualizar de acuerdo al idioma seleccionado. Al escoger el idioma estoy cambiando su cultura con el comando `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` y asi mismo estoy renombrando las variables con un archivo de recursos pero el formulario hijo no logra actualizarse asi llame ese archivo de recursos en el Load ni al iniciar los componentes del mismo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Ofreces muy poca información y así es difícil poder dar respuesta. De forma que esta que te muestro no sé si te sirve o no. Cuando yo he tenido que hacer que una aplicación que soporte varios idiomas lo he hecho de esta forma ya que Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); no te va a traducir el texto de tu aplicación. Si lo que se pretende es cambiar el texto que vemos en la aplicación yo lo hago así:

```
using System.Collections;

namespace RootScope
{
    public enum CurrentLanguage
    {
       Spanish = 0,
       English = 1
    }
    public class Language
    {
       // Creamos una Hashtable que contendrá el idioma seleccionado.
       static public Hashtable GetItemText = new Hashtable();
       // Lenguaje por defecto
       static public CurrentLanguage Default = CurrentLanguage.Spanish;

       // Cargamos el idioma que pasamos en el parámetro
       public void Load(CurrentLanguage p_Language)
       { 
           GetItemText.Clear();

           if (p_Language == CurrentLanguage.Spanish)
           {
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT1", "Aceptar");
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT2", "Modificar");
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT3", "Cancelar");
           }
           if (p_Language == CurrentLanguage.English)
           {
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT1", "Accept");
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT2", "Modify");
               GetItemText.Add("#BUT3", "Cancel");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

La clase creada me permite rellenar un Hashtable con el idioma deseado de forma que tan sólo resta hacer que cambie el texto de cada elemento en la aplicación de forma que en el caso que expongo en el evento Load del formulario pondría así:

```
private void frmMiFormulario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Inicializamos las propiedades Text de nuestros objetos de la interfaz
     // en este caso del ejemplo sólo botones, pero pueden ser menus, labels...
     button1.Text = Language.GetItemText["#BUT1"];
     button2.Text = Language.GetItemText["#BUT2"];
     button3.Text = Language.GetItemText["#BUT3"];
}
```

Yo lo que hice en su día es guardar el valor del idioma que tengo elegido en la aplicación, esto lo puedes hacer de varias formas en el registro del sistema o bien en un archivo de configuración; en cualquier caso yo cargo el idioma al inicio de la aplicación de esta forma:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Aquí obtendrías el idioma para la aplicación
        CurrentLanguage curLAN = GetCurrentLanguage();
        // Lo cargamos en la Hashtable
        Language.Load(curLAN);

        // Ejecutamos y mostramos nuestra aplicación
        Application.Run(new frmMiFormulario());
    }
}
```

Si se quiere que el idioma se cambie y aplique en el momento con la aplicación abierta habría que actualizar todos los formularios abiertos.

Evidentemente la función Load de nuestra clase Language es sumamente simplona tan sólo muestro la técnica. Se podría mejorar haciendo que lea de un fichero todas las cadenas de texto lo que nos permite también aplicar un traductor y migrar fácilmente a otros idiomas partiendo de nuestro lenguaje base.